# Which OpenSSL commands update the CA database index file?

Tags: openssl, csr

Have I understood correctly that when CSR is signed with **openssl *x509*** tool, a CA database index file is not updating ? As opposite, when signing with **openssl *ca*** tool, then index file is updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct. `openssl x509` is only a tool to manipulate and create certificates, but it is not a standalone CA and does not keep any status. Whereas `openssl ca` is described in the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ca.html) as:

> The ca command is a **minimal CA application**. It can be used to sign certificate requests in a variety of forms and generate CRLs it also **maintains a text database of issued certificates and their status**.

This *text database* includes the *index file* you refer too.

Comment: Also, in the [CA Database documentation](http://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cadb.html), it states that "the `openssl ca` command uses this file as certificate database."